# Start application with recent document only using the keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I usually use keyboard navigation, if possible. For some weeks, I have problems with selecting an application with a particular recent document from the startmenu, and I ask you for the best way to use only the keyboard.

I press the (WIN) key to open the startmenu. I enter some characters to look for an application. Usually, Windows select the correct one. Now I try to navigate to recent documents with the tab key or shift+tab. Windows select many links, but not in the recent document area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it: To switch to the area with the recent documents, you have to use the arrow keys. That's all.